# Facebook Reverse Chronological Order. comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, reverse, classification

In the link:
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/
In comments he gives the following code:

```
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js = d.getElementsByTagName FJS (s) [0];
        if (d.getElementById (id)) return;
        js = d.createElement (s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "/ / connect.facebook.net / en_US / all.js XFBML # = 1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore (js, FJS);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Using this code are the comments by Social Classification.
  I wonder.
How can I put Pattern: Reverse Chronological Order.

My intention and create an area of Applications
• a species within the Chat Channel.

Keeping Current Reviews more always on top instead of underneath.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can try it:

```
<fb:comments href="(...)" num_posts="20" order_by="reverse_time"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use `data-order-by="reverse_time"`

like this :

```
< div class="fb-comments"
      data-href="***URL****"
      data-num-posts="20"
      data-mobile="false"
      data-order-by="reverse_time"
      data-width="450">< /div >
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no option on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ to preselect the ordering of the comments.  Each user will have to do so.

However, you can create a facebook application that can mimic the comments plugin and then you can order them as you see fit. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

Happy coding!